# Python: apply lambda to each element of a list in a row

Tags: python, pandas, list, lambda

How can I apply lambda to echa element of list in a row?

I have a column with list of 2 elements in each row.

Those elelemts are strings and I want to make them ints.

Now: ['111', '222'] Then: [111, 222]

How to pass iteration thru each element of a list in a row?

```
df.column.apply(lambda x: int(x) for x in...
```

And I'm stuck here not knowing how to iterate since I already told lambda to work with x where x is a certain cell.

Thank you in advance.

Data Sample screenshot enclosed.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3u0aX.png)
The problem is with 'coords' column.

Comment: [tag:pandas]? Show a sample of your data structure please…?

Comment: @deceze Yep. I don't know if I did it right with the sample (enclosed it as a screenshot to a question)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried indexing into the list?

`df.column.apply(lambda x: [int(x[0]), int(x[1])] for x in...`

**EDIT:**

As your column sometimes contains None, try this:

`df.column.apply(lambda x: x if pd.isnull(x) else [int(x[0]), int(x[1])]`

This assumes that the problem values are None and not something like ['111', None]

Comment: Returns 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. How to exclude Nones from iteration? if x.isna() == False doen't work..

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:**
I don't know why but this worked:

```
df.column.apply(lambda x: (float(x[0]), float(x[1])) if pd.isna([x]).any() == False else x)
```